# Custom stylesheet not loading

Tags: customization, page-template

I have added following code in my theme functions.php

```
function my_loginlcustomization() {

wp_register_style('custom_loginstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/login/login-styles.css', __FILE__);
wp_enqueue_style('custom_loginstyle');
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_loginlcustomization');
```

Custom login page:

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name: Login

 */
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login Form</title>

</head>

<body>


<?php wp_login_form(); ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

But no effect on page.

Comment: There is no function in your template which can initiate your function call.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code in your themes functions.php file:

```
// custom login for theme
function my_loginlcustomization() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/login/login-styles.css" />';
}

add_action('login_head', 'my_loginlcustomization');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a page as a custom login form. You should enqueue your style in that particular page.

```
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_loginlcustomization',10);
function my_loginlcustomization() {
    // Check the page
    if (is_page_template('custom-login.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('custom_loginstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/login/login-styles.css');
    }
}
```

This will check if you are on the login page, and print the styles if necessary.

Replace the `custom-login.php` with your page's template name.

Comment: Is there if condition necessary, I have checked it without if condition and there is no effect

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam If it doesn't work even without the conditional, then there might be a problem with your theme's header or actions. Your page does not have the `wp_head();` function, it is necessary for styles and scripts to be outputted. Put `wp_head();` right before the `</head>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dedicated action to enqueue script or style in the login page  : `login_enqueue_scripts`, this action will work exactly like `wp_enqueue_scripts` but will be fired only on the login page.

You can read more details [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_enqueue_scripts)